# SQL query to retrieve the last record

Tags: sql

I have table article related to another table article_has_type

The structure of article table is

```
    CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `titre` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NULL,
)
```

structure  for table article_has_type is

```
CREATE TABLE `arhastypes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `article_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

I want to get the last article added to each type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `id` column is `AUTO INCREMENT`, you can do this:

To get the last record in `articles`:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles)
```

To get the details of last records in `arhastypes` for each types:

```
SELECT * FROM arhastypes WHERE id IN 
            (SELECT MAX(id) FROM arhastypes
             GROUP BY type_id)
```

**EDIT:**

To select records from both tables, you can do this:

```
SELECT ART.id,ART.titre,ART.description,ARH.id as arhastypes_id,ARH.type_id
FROM arhastypes ARH JOIN
     articles ART ON ARH.article_id=ART.id
WHERE ARH.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM arhastypes
                 GROUP BY type_id)
```

Comment: OP probably wants the info from `articles` instead of (or maybe in addition to?) `arhastypes` in your second query, but this is still better than the other answers.

Comment: @TiAmoLaky: It is a pleasure, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Are looking for this?

```
Select * from articles where id in (select max(id) from articles)
Select * from arhastypes where id in (select max(id) from arhastypes)
```

Comment: I don't think so. "get the last article added to each type" You're simply getting the last article added, and the last type-article relationship added.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from articles where id in 
(select max(arhastypes.article_id) from arhastypes where type_id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query should give you the last article added to each type(assuming `id` column is `AUTO INCREMENT`):

```
select arhastypes.type_id, articles.title, articles.description from articles join arhastypes on arhastypes.article_id = articles.id order by articles.id desc group by arhastypes.type_id
```

Comment: "order by articles.id desc group by arhastypes.type_id" Unfortunately, the `GROUP BY` happens before the `ORDER BY`, so you will not know which record is selected by the `GROUP BY` when you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select top 1 from articles
order by ID desc

select top 1 from arhastypes
order by ID desc
```

Comment: SELECT TOP is only available in T-SQL. The OP has not indicated which database system they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Select  A.*
From    Articles    A
Where   A.id In
(
    Select  Max(article_id)
    From    arhastypes
    Where   type_id = @type_id
)
```

To get the last article added to each type for every type, you can do:

```
Select  T.type_id, A.*
From    Articles    A
Join    arhastypes  T On A.id = T.article_id
Where   A.id In
(
    Select  Max(article_id)
    From    arhastypes
    Group By type_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works every time:

```
Select  A.*
From    Articles    A
ORDER BY A.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```